# Multiple video elements vs. one video element to multiple canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-video, transparency

I am working on a project where I require using a large amount of video elements, all with the same source. An example: a page with a list of products on an online store, where I want to display a custom video asset when the user hovers if a given product is sold out. In that case, if a whole page of products is sold out, I’d be loading a lot of video elements.

Although I haven’t run into any issues doing it this way, I’m wondering if there are better methods or ways to optimize this, like rendering one video element to a bunch of canvases instead of creating a bunch of video elements. The ability to synchronize playback across video elements isn’t necessary, and I wouldn’t be applying any effects via canvas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DannyM Investigate using CSS option `z-index` for layering the "sold-out" video tag above all other items/elements in the page. You can solve it with using only one tag, just change it's on-screen position using Javascript to update CSS options (like `top` and `left`).

Comment: Since you're showing them as a result of hovering over an item, can we conclude that only one of these videos will ever be visible at the same time? If so, why use multiple elements? Just move a single `<video>` where it needs to be (and I mean "move it" in DOM, if necessary).

Comment: @Kaiido OK, I definitely overthought that. Moving it in the DOM would be the most logical and efficient solution. Thanks for the suggestion!